# Is it possible to use the PayPal API Web service to process Website Payments Standard payments?

Tags: c#-4.0, paypal

I already have the HTML form method implemented but it's very slow encrypting the form data and redirecting to PayPal & an unencrypted form is not an option.

What I would ideally like to do is something similar to how Google Checkout Integration works. Connect to the PayPal web service, send across the contents of the basket and then redirect the user to paypal checkout.

It this possible using the PayPal API web service?

Answer (score 1):

if you are in the UK then what you need is the Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution. Then you can use an API to connect to Paypal checkout. Call their Telesales team and they will point you to Website Payments Pro Hosted Solution.